# Why .settings file is missing

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I cannot build storage in Maven. The settings file is missing. There is such code in jenkinsfile. How does it refer if it is not in the repository itself? Help me understand

```
    stages {

        stage("Copying credentials files") {
            steps {
                withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'settings.xml', variable: 'SETTINGS'), file(credentialsId: 'settings-security.xml', variable: 'SETTINGS_SECURITY')]) {
                    bat '''COPY %SETTINGS% %WORKSPACE%'''
                    bat '''COPY %SETTINGS_SECURITY% %WORKSPACE%'''
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        bat "mvn clean install -s settings.xml -Dsettings.security=settings-security.xml -DTagConfigFile=${configFile} -DTAGS=${tags}"
                    } catch (err) {
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                        throw err
                    } finally {
                        stage("Allure report") {
                            allure([
                                    commandline      : '2.8.0',
                                    includeProperties: false,
                                    jdk              : '',
                                    properties       : [],
                                    reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                                    report           : 'target/allure-report',
                                    results          : [[path: 'target/allure-results']]
                            ])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jenkinsfile was nothing to do with. It turned out that settings.xml was deleted from the project by mistake by another programmer. Adding it solved the problem